# Sequelize with sqlite3 doesn't create a database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Could you please help me to solve the problem?
I use sqlite3 with sequelize npm package. After running migrations I don't see errors in console but I also don't see any database file. Also I can run migrations again and again, it doesn't look like correct behavior.
Here is my **/config/config.js** file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    test: {
        username: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'database_test.sqlite'),
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        logging: console.log,
        operatorsAliases: false
    }
};
```

Here is **migrations/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-create-appeal.js** file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('appeals', {
        appealId: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.UUID
        },
        name: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        description: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(511)
        },
        createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
    }),
    down: queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('appeals')
};
```

Here is **models/index.js** file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.js'))[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Here is **models/appeal.js** file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Appeal = sequelize.define('appeals', {
        appealId: {
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            validate: {
                isUUID: 4
            },
            get() {
                return this.getDataValue('appealId').toLowerCase();
            }
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(511)
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'appeals'
    });
    Appeal.associate = models => {
        // associations can be defined here
    };
    return Appeal;
};
```

Another strange thing: if I put console log or error throwing in **models/index.js**, I'll see nothing, so that nodejs doesn't execute file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a reason: it should be `storage` instead of `database` in config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    test: {
        username: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        storage: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'database_test.sqlite'),
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        logging: console.log
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

**./config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    development: {
        username: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'database_test.sqlite'),
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        logging: true,
        operatorsAliases: false
    }
};
```

**.sequelizerc**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    'models-path': path.resolve('./models'),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve('./seeders'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('./migrations'),
     'config': path.resolve('./config', 'config.js')
};
```